# Program an Omnikey PinPad 3821 to show a custom text on the screen

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I'm working on a java card project and I've just bought an Omnikey 3821 PinPad to use it as a smart card reader and pin keyboard for users. What I want, is to show a custom text on the screen of the pinpad expl (Instead of HID OMNIKEY 3821 I want to show : THIS IS A CUSTOM TEXT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [CARDMAN SPE-API](http://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/14872) available which allows you to manage displayed text to some extent but it includes only native C library so you will probably need to use JNI to make it work from Java.

Comment: what  CARDMAN SPE-API is used for please ?

Comment: It contains a library with C functions that allows you to show custom text on the screen of the pinpad - exactly what you asked for.